# gstreamer support multiple src or pipieline?

Tags: video, gstreamer, playbin2

I use gstreamer to play video.I want to know whether gstreamer support two or more pipelines to play videos?That is I want to use gstreamer to play two or more pads videos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with "play two or more pads videos".

Anyway I'm going to try to answer the first question.

Yes GStreamer has support to play N videos at the same time. You can have a pipeline for each video playing or just have a single pipeline with multiple videos inside.

In case you are using playbin you will need to have a pipeline for each video (playbin is already the pipeline). If you need all the videos to play synchronized or in the same pipeline it might be easier to have a single pipeline playing all the videos, but then you need to assemble the pipeline yourself. Using uridecodebin and playsink is likely the easier route on this path.

Comment: I have problems when using videomixer.Can you tell me how to use videomixer correctly with xvimagesink? **[Here is the link: How to use videomixer element for gstreamer?]**  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234369/how-to-use-videomixer-element-for-gstreamer)